# Datagrid as a background to create new cards in Livecode

Tags: datagrid, livecode

I need to have a datagrid which must as part of other items form the "background" of a card that I use to create new cards from. All works ok but I note that DGH/LC picks up the characteristics (number of lines and contents) of the base DG regardless of defining it as group "xyz" of this card (or card "abc"). I tried various ways to overcome  this - is this something for DGH or a general LC issue - or I am I missing something in terms of naming conventions ?

Kind regards
Danny

Comment: You should add an example of what you have tried. Do you have a code example where it doesn't work?

Comment: Solved the riddle. Cannot use a Datagrid group as Background to automatically populate a new card because it retains the ID number and the data referenced. The ID has to change - so I used "Copy" onto the new card in stead and that gives it a new ID number and therefore is unique in the system.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but it's possible that all instances of the datagrid are sharing the same template, which would explain what you're seeing.  Your solution of copying it would create a new template for each instance of the datagrid.
Pete